# Prevent pandas from alphabetizing columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
holders = pd.DataFrame({
    "Rank": rank,
    "Address": address,
    "Quantity": quantity,
    "Percentage": percent
})

holders.to_csv('holders.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

However, when I open the csv file, the columns are organized like this: "Address", "Percentage", "Quantity", and "Rank"

How can I fix my code to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Try `holders[['Rank','Address','Quantity','Percentage']].to_csv("holders.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: You can define the order in columns parameter available in pd.to_csv: check out the documentation - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html